# How do set theories base on Intuitionistic Logic deal with ordinals?

Tags: logic, set-theory, constructive-mathematics, intuitionistic-logic

In my opinion, the notion of ordinals plays a key role in ZF set theory. A lot of important notions are defined by recursive on ordinals, like von Neumann hierarchy, Gödel's constructible universe. This makes me think that a set theory without the full force of ordinals will not be very useful. However, I also notice that in developing properties of ordinals the use of the law of excluded middle is crucial. Since Intuitionistic Logic reject the rule of excluded middle, I'm a bit curious that how do  those set theories that are based on Intuitionistic Logic deal with ordinals?

Comment: You can see [Set Theory: Constructive and Intuitionistic ZF](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/set-theory-constructive/) as well as John Bell, [Intuitionistic Set Theory](https://books.google.it/books?id=UnuGoAEACAAJ), College Publications (2014)

Comment: How does a great chef cook without pans, pots, and with a blindfold on and allowing only to use the thumb and pinky of their non dominant hand cook?

Comment: Intuitionistic logic does **not** reject LEM.  It just doesn't give it to you as a rule of inference.  You are free to assume it on whatever you want, or to assume axioms for which LEM of some property is a consequence of the axioms.  Since the only relation in ZF is $\in$, it amounts to assuming LEM on $\in$.

Comment: @AsafKaragila sorry I don't think I get your meaning……

Comment: @DanielV eh, I have read some introduction to IZF and CZF, it seems that your suggestions is not the standard approach……

Comment: This might be important: https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/plump+ordinal

Comment: More on the [plump ordinals](https://homotopytypetheory.org/2014/02/22/surreals-plump-ordinals/)

Comment: @CensiLI Yes you are probably right.  A set theory developed with constructivism in mind will probably better very different than classical set theory with LEM added.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In constructive set theory the most fruitful definition of ordinal is "a transitive set $x$ such that for all $y \in x$, y is also transitive." Note that in $\mathbf{ZF}$ this agrees with the usual definition. It's important to note that in intuitionistic set theory one still has $\in$-induction and can use it to define operations by recursion on ordinals.

Often in $\mathbf{ZF}$ definitions by recursion on ordinals are defined by splitting into two cases depending on whether an ordinal is a successor or a limit. However, this is often unnecessary and both cases can be combined into one. For example, in classical logic, one defines addition $\alpha + \beta$ by $\alpha + (\beta + 1) := (\alpha + \beta) + 1$ for successor and $\alpha + \lambda := \bigcup_{\beta < \lambda} (\alpha + \lambda)$ for limit. But you can also define $\alpha + \beta$ by $\alpha + \beta := \bigcup_{\gamma \in \beta} ((\alpha + \gamma) + 1)$. This works in intuitionistic logic and is equivalent to the usual definition in $\mathbf{ZF}$.

Alternatively, it is possible to use inductive definitions in place of ordinals for many proofs.

See Aczel and Rathjen, [*Constructive Set Theory*](http://www1.maths.leeds.ac.uk/~rathjen/book.pdf). Ordinals are in section 9.4 and inductive definitions are in chapter 12.

Comment: I want to put some explanation on your answer: the dichotomy of ordinals into successor and limit case is not available in intuitionistic and constructive ZF. Hence the definition of addition for ordinals which is not relied on the dichotomy is not just sufficient, but necessary.